# Importing the PIL (Pillow) module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why am I able to do this in Python 3.7:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("hardcastle-crags-3462894.jpg")
```

But **not** this, which I had understood to be the same thing:

```
import PIL
im = PIL.Image.open("hardcastle-crags-3462894.jpg")
```

The latter gives result:

```
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'
```

I had understood these to be the same thing. Why does one work and the other does not?

Comment: `PIL.Image` is a sub-module, which is not automatically imported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question (now that I understand properly).

In Python, you can import:

1. modules - single files e.g. something.py; or
2. packages - directories containing one or more .py files, and always one file called __init__.py which designates the directory as a package

In this case, the statement:

```
import PIL
```

Is really the same as saying "*import the __init__.py file in the PIL directory*". In this specific case, that __init__.py file does not import or otherwise make available any class or other module called "Image", so my subsequent reference to it in example 2 in my initial post import fails.

In contrast, the statement:

```
from PIL import Image
```

is interpreted a bit differently. This is really the same as saying "*look in the package directory PIL for a module called Image and import it*".

So you can see that the import statement is actually a bit context dependent. It can mean different things in different circumstances.

[This](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/) is an excellent resource that explains the different ways in which the import statement can function depending on context.